# how gson can identify between a class instance and an array?

Tags: java, android, json, error-handling, gson

I send some data to my server and get a response.

In case there was an error the response is a class instance:

```
{
errorCode (int),

errorMsg (String)
}
```

In a success case the response is an items array.

I have tried to run the following code and got an error:

code:

```
private void afterServerOfferResponse(final Gson gson,
                        String result) {
                    ServerErrorMessage serverErrorMessage = gson.fromJson(
                            result, ServerErrorMessage.class);

if (serverErrorMessage.errorCode == 0) {
                        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Offer>>() {
                        }.getType();
                        mOffersList = gson.fromJson(result, collectionType);
                        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(OffersListActivity.this,
                                mOffersList);
                        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
```

how would you check for an error case without changing the server response too much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `try-catch` block to handle the exception. Only when you try to parse the data, it will be validated if its valid `JSON` response or error.

First try to parse `Array Class` instance and if `JSON` exception , then parse with `ServerErrorMessage class`

Add like this, and handle the exception when `Syntax Exception`

```
 try{
        ServerErrorMessage serverErrorMessage = gson.fromJson(
            result, ServerErrorMessage.class);
    }catch (JsonSyntaxException e){
        // handle the exception
    }
    catch (JsonIOException e){
        // handle the exception
    }
    catch (JsonParseException e){
        // handle the exception
    }catch (IOException e){
        // handle the exception
    }
```

Another way is to use `org.json.JSONObject` like this

```
  private boolean isValidJsonResponse(String responseString){
    try {
        new JSONObject(responseString);
        return true;
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: but both the response-with-error and list-of-items are valid, i just want to differentiate between them. Is it right to put the no-error format in the catch block?

Comment: Don't do it inside catch-block. Have two different method. First call a method to parse with Array Class, if any exception then call other method to parse with Error Message

Comment: As explained above, move the ServerErrorMessage parsing into a new method and if valid response code, then parse with Array Class